# Can i get a video to show through part of an image (from behind) in html?

Tags: html, css, video

Is there anyway i can get a video to show through part of an image?

I'm trying to create a website where people can create their own background scene for studying.

In my code below, image1 is an image of a wall with a window. I'd like the user to be able to click buttons to change the video in the background of the window (eg change from a rainy scene to snow etc).

I've only managed to get the video floating on top of the image, in a specif position aligning to the window, which only really works on full screen pc. preferably i'd have the video showing through part of the image, so it doesn't look like it's just floating on top of the window.

I'd also like it to work for different devices (mobiles, tablets etc), but this is something i'll probably look into later once i've got the basic design done.

Any help would be appreciated!
thanks

JS in head

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function changevid(buttonlink) {

document.getElementById('change').src = buttonlink;

}

</script>
```

style in head

```
<style>

    #window_container {

    background: url('pics/image1.jpg') no-repeat top left transparent;
     width: 1920px; /* Adjust TV image width */
    height: 1080px; /* Adjust TV image height */
    position: relative
    }

    #window_container video {
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:300px
    }

</style>
```

HTML in body

```
    <h1 style="color:blue";>

    Build your own relaxing soundscape!

    </h1>


<p style="color:blue";>Click the buttons below to create your ideal soundscape, perfect background for studying, or relaxing, whatever works for you</p>




<button onClick="changevid('videos/vid1_stream.mp4')">Video 1</button>
<button onClick="changevid('videos/vid2_rain.mp4')">Video 2</button>
<button onClick="changevid('videos/vid3_snow.mp4')">Video 3</button>


<div id="window_container">

<video controls autoplay id="change" height="600">
  <source src="videos/vid1_stream.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>



<div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share the image and the video too

Answer (score 1):

split it to `<img>` and `<video>` in the same div. the img should be a `.png` for transparency and you can style it something like this:

```
<div>
    <video ...>
    <img ...>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```